# Changing number of table elements displayed on page resets my search results

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have numerous data displayed in a table, let's say a long list of users (first name & last name), so I set up a paging feature to display the elements by pages via the PagedList NuGet package. I was inspired by this tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/sorting-filtering-and-paging-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

I implemented a drop-down list in my view, so that I can directly **choose the number of elements to display** per page. I managed to include a jQuery script that makes the page size update whenever the drop-down list has a new selected value.

[image: DropDownList allowing to set the number of elements to display per page]

Using the mentioned tutorial , I also added a search feature: submitting a string in a **search form** allows to filter the data.

[image: Search form]

My problem is: changing the page size by selecting a new value in the drop-down list **after** having done a search doesn't work: the search results are reset, all the entries being displayed instead. I guess I forgot to pass some parameter somewhere but I just can't figure out where...

Here is my controller:

```
public ActionResult Index(string sortOrder, string currentFilter, string searchString, int? page, int? PageSize)

    // Sort order is passed to view in order to keep it intact while clicking in another page link
    ViewBag.CurrentSort = sortOrder;

    // Ascending or descending sorting by first or last name according to sortOrder value
    ViewBag.LastNameSortParm = String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortOrder) ? "lastname_desc" : "";
    ViewBag.FirstNameSortParm = sortOrder == "firstname" ? "firstname_desc" : "firstname";

    // Not sure here
    if (searchString == null)
    {
        searchString = currentFilter;
    }

    // Pass filtering string to view in order to maintain filtering when paging
    ViewBag.CurrentFilter = searchString;

    var users = from u in _db.USER select u;

    // FILTERING
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
    {
        users = users.Where(u => u.lastname.Contains(searchString)
                              || u.firstname.Contains(searchString)
    }

    // Ascending or descending filtering by first/last name
    switch (sortOrder)
    {
    case "lastname": // Ascending last name
        users = users.OrderBy(u => u.lastname);
        break;
    case "lastname_desc": // Descending last name
        users = users.OrderByDescending(u => u.lastname);
        break;
    case "firstname": // Ascending first name
        users = users.OrderBy(u => u.firstname);
        break;
    case "firstname_desc": // Descending first name
        users = users.OrderByDescending(u => u.firstname);
        break;
    default:
        users = users.OrderBy(u => u.lastname);
        break;
}


// DROPDOWNLIST FOR UPDATING PAGE SIZE
int count = _db.USER.OrderBy(e => e.Id).Count(); // Total number of elements

// Populate DropDownList
ViewBag.PageSize = new List<SelectListItem>() {
    new SelectListItem { Text = "10", Value = "10", Selected = true },
    new SelectListItem { Text = "25", Value = "25" },
    new SelectListItem { Text = "50", Value = "50" },
    new SelectListItem { Text = "100", Value = "100" },
    new SelectListItem { Text = "All", Value = count.ToString() }
};

int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);
int pageSize = (PageSize ?? 10);
ViewBag.psize = pageSize;

return View(users.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));
}
```

And my Index.cshtml view:

```html
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.2.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () { // Submit pageSizeForm when another pageSize value is selected
    $("#pageSize").change(function () {
        $("#pageSizeForm").submit();
    });
});
</script>

@model PagedList.IPagedList<AfpaSIPAdmin.Models.USER>
@using PagedList.Mvc;
<link href="~/Content/PagedList.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Users management";
}

<h1>Users management</h1>

<!-- Creating a new entry in table -->
<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create new user", "Create")
</p>


<!-- Filtering table entries -->
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Users", FormMethod.Get, new { id = "filterForm" }))
{
    <p>
        Filter: @Html.TextBox("SearchString", ViewBag.CurrentFilter as string, new { @placeholder = "First or last name..." })
        <input type="submit" value="Apply"/>
    </p>
}

<!-- Display table -->
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.ActionLink("Last name", "Index", new {
                sortOrder = ViewBag.LastNameSortParm,
                currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter
            })
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.ActionLink("First name", "Index", new {
                sortOrder = ViewBag.FirstNameSortParm,
                currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter
            })
        </th>
        <th style="min-width: 170px"></th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
           <td style = "min-width: 150px">
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.lastname)
            </td>
            <td style = "min-width: 150px">
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.firstname)
            </td>

            <td> <!-- Using images as buttons for actions -->
                <a href="@Url.Action("Edit", "Users", new { id = item.Id })" title="Edit">
                    <img src="~/Content/images/edit.gif" />
                </a>
                <a href="@Url.Action("Details", "Users", new { id = item.Id })" title="Details">
                    <img src="~/Content/images/info.gif" />
                </a>
                <a href="@Url.Action("Delete", "Users", new { id = item.Id })" title="Delete">
                    <img src="~/Content/images/delete.gif" />
                </a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>

<br/>

<!-- Paging -->
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Users", FormMethod.Get, new { id = "pageSizeForm" }))
{
    <div class="pager">
        Page @(Model.PageCount < Model.PageNumber ? 0 : Model.PageNumber) sur @Model.PageCount<br/>

        @Model.Count of @Model.TotalItemCount elements 

        @Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("Index", new {
            page,
            sortOrder = ViewBag.CurrentSort,
            currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter,
            searchString = ViewBag.CurrentFilter,
            pageSize = ViewBag.psize
        }))

        <!-- DropDownList for setting page size -->
        Elements per page :
        @Html.DropDownList("pageSize")
    </div>
}
```

Comment: First, never submit a form on the change event of a dropdownlist (use a submit button). You should have one form including both the textbox and the dropdownlist.

Comment: Not sure what your expecting to happen - when your 2nd form is submitted, all you send to the controller is a value for `pageSize` - every other parameter will be their default (which for `currentFilter` is `null`)

Comment: I guess you do not need to pass `searchString` param at search  `Html.PagedListPager` from *Paging* region

Comment: @StephenMuecke Why not with a change event? I find it much more comfortable than a submit button. Security reasons?

Comment: You can try to debug and check the correct filter behavior  if you use VS

Comment: And what about users who use the keyboard and use the arrow keys to navigate through the options - the moment the press the down key, then form is submitted and returned with 10 records when they actually wanted 50

Comment: Let the user make their selection (and check it) and then allow them to submit

Comment: @StephenMuecke How can I send more than one parameter value to the controller? In that case, sortOrder, currentFilter, searchString (?), page and PageSize? Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is because you have 2 forms. When you submit the first form containing the textbox, the only value you send back to the controller is `SearchString` and all the other parameters in your method will be their default (for example when you return the view, `PageSize` will default to `null` and therefore return only 10 records even if the user previously selected say 50.

Likewise, when you submit the 2nd form containing dropdownlist for the page size, the value of `SearchString` will be `null` because its not sent in the request.

You need to have one form only containing both form controls. And if you wanted to send additional properties, for example the current sort order, then you can add those as query string values in the form element (for example, `@using(Html.BeginForm("Index", "Users", new { sortOrder = .... }, FormMethod.Get))`

I would also strongly recommend you use a view model containing the properties you need in the view and strongly bind to them rather than using `ViewBag`

```
public class UsersVM
{
    public string SearchString { get; set; }
    public int PageSize { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> PageSizeOptions { get; set; }
    .....
    public IPagedList<USER> Users { get; set; }
}
```

View

```
@model UsersVM
...
@using(Html.BeginForm("Index", "Users", FormMethod.Get))
{
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.SearchString)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SearchString)

    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.PageSize)
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.PageSize, Model.PageSizeOptions)

    <input type="submit" value="Filter" />
}
....
<div class="pager">
    Page @(Model.Users.PageCount < Model.Users.PageNumber ? 0 : Model.Users.PageNumber)
    ....
    @Html.PagedListPager(Model.Users, page => Url.Action("Index", new {
        page,
        sortOrder = Model.CurrentSort,
        currentFilter = Model.CurrentFilter,
        searchString = Model.CurrentFilter,
        pageSize = Model.PageSize
    }))
</div>
```

and in the controller method, initialize a new instance of `UsersVM` and assign its properties

```
public ActionResult Index(string sortOrder, string currentFilter, string searchString, int? page, int? pageSize)
{
    UsersVM model = new UsersVM();
    ....
    var users = from u in _db.USER select u;
    ....
    pageSize = pageSize ?? 10;
    model.PageSize = pageSize.Value;
    model.Users = users.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize);
    model.PageSizeOptions = new List<SelectListItem> { .... };
    return View(model);
}
```

Comment: Great! One remaining problem though: when having done a search, going to page 2, 3, 4... resets the search results! The currentFilter and searchString are null

Comment: Have you assigned `Model.CurrentFilter = searchString; (as you previously did it for `ViewBag.CurrentFilter = searchString;) in the controller method, so `currentFilter = Model.CurrentFilter,` in the `@Html.PagedListPager()` options would pass it back again.

Comment: Indeed, I unintentionally had commented it! Works great now!